# HikariPool can't initialize for the spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hikaricp

I have tried to connect directly to MySQL using JDBC driver class and it worked fine (I also have a connected DB Browser plugin). However, when I try to connect from my spring application I receive the following exception:

```
2024-01-01T17:44:36.359+02:00  INFO 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo \[name: default\]

2024-01-01T17:44:36.402+02:00  INFO 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final

2024-01-01T17:44:36.427+02:00  INFO 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled

2024-01-01T17:44:36.614+02:00  INFO 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer

2024-01-01T17:44:36.650+02:00  INFO 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2024-01-01T17:44:37.775+02:00 ERROR 52319 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

...

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at application.Main.main(Main.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
```

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>UdemyBlogApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/blog
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

I tried to use various approaches, such as adding and removing Hikari dependency in pom file, changing properties of application.properties file but nothing worked out.

Comment: Are you sure your DB is on port 3036 and not 3006?

Comment: it's 3036 for sure

Comment: I'm really silly, it was 3306, I made a typo... Thank you for your time

Comment: Hey @mark2909 please help us clarify: so the port number of your MySQL Server instance is **3306** and your app is configured to connect to the instance on **3306** as well? And Hikari CP still fails with the error you posted on your question?